# Having trouble with automating Google searches with text extracted from Tesseract-OCR

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, script, ocr

Having some trouble with a project and hopefully someone can help.

I'm trying to take extracted text from [tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/) and use that text as the search query of Google Chrome searches. My shell script can extract the text and launch Chrome, but I cant figure out how to send the text to the search bar of Chrome.

Below are some pictures of my script.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post linked above for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.  You can also contact the software developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: This is not a Mac issue per se.  the issue you are having is creating the search query URI to pass to Chrome when it's launched.  You need to research how do do that through Google.

Comment: Does Chrome on Mac support Applescript? That might be a way to make it a Mac question if the question is re-written a little...

Comment: It's purely a "how to use Google Search from Python" question

Comment: Not quite, I can find many write ups on "how to use Google Search from Python" but nothing that explains how to feed OCR text into the python script that launches the google search.

Comment: Looking at the screenshots it seems that you've solved that part ("shell script can extract the text and launch Chrome"), so it seems that the problem is with the search part. If you want to reopen please make it more obvious which part doesn't work (and by all means replace the screenshots by actual code). And as mentioned already: stackoverflow.com is the better place for this.